# Unable to install Channels

Tags: django, installation, pip, pipenv, channel

I created a virtual environment using `pipenv shell`. Then, after installing Django using `pipenv install django==2.2`, I used the commands `pipenv install channels` and `python -m pip install -U channels` to install Channels, but I am unable to do so. The error was:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/<br/>
```

BTW, I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Code latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have enough reputation on this account to comment, so I have to write an answer: the error tells you exactly what is wrong: your pipenv cannot find MVC++ 14.0.

You can simply install MVC++ 14.0 and make sure to restart your pipenv so it can register it in its PATH.